# Windows 8.1 Task Manager network usage and Virtualbox

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, virtualbox

My question is related to this question:
[How to make windows task manager to show network usage?](https://superuser.com/questions/626073/how-to-make-windows-task-manager-to-show-network-usage)
but I can't post there, because my reputation is 1.

I have Virtualbox 4.3.16 (Latest) installed on Win8.1 x64 fully updated.

Windows task manager shows no network usage, because it monitors the wrong connection (Virtualbox bridged connection).

If I uninstall Virtualbox it starts to work immediately, but it's not enough to just disable the bridged connection.

Can I somehow convince Windows Task Manager to monitor the other connection or use another network setup in virtualbox that doesn't interfere with Task Manager?

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to folow:**

1. Right-Click on *internetconnection* (e.g. Inventec PCIe GBE Family Controller) in `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections\`
2. Uncheck *virtualbox bridged networking driver*

Answer (score 0):

I asked this almost a year ago and I believe the bug has  been fixed since. The issue is at least not present anymore on my machine.