# Windows Task Manager Cannot Get Network Usage After Create Network Bridge

Tags: windows-10, networking, task-manager, bridge

My task manager is okay before I create bridge for my home network.
[image]

After create a bridge between `Wifi` and `Ethernet` like this
[image]

My network usage totally cannot show on task manager, But internet and network still okay. How to fix that?

[image]

I try check this link https://superuser.com/a/820710 because I Think that answer is correct, but I cannot found **Virtualbox Bridged Networking Driver**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue some months ago
My solution was to mark the bridge as my default device and i also restart my system.
Hope that helps

Comment: How to mark the bridge as default device?